# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Login on home page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want a login form on my home page. In `index.cshtml` I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AccountController", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div>
            <div class="usernametb">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginMod.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="usernametb">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginMod.UserName, new { style = "width:150px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginMod.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div>
            <div class="pwtb">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginMod.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="pwtb">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginMod.Password, new { style = "width:150px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginMod.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="rememberme">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LoginMod.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginMod.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </div>
        <div><input class="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Log In" /></div>
}
```

I reference this model:

```
namespace memsite.Models
{
    public class MemEvent
    {
        public LoginModel LoginMod { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to hit this account controller login action, but it never hits the controller, it just re-directs to `/AccountController/Login` which doesn't exist. Also, the validation controls are not working...

```
namespace memsite.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

(I am brand new to MVC having left webforms land forever.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Account instead of AccountController in your form.  ASP MVC is based on naming conventions and the Controller is implied.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the controller in below line

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AccountController", FormMethod.Post)) {
```

To

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) {
```

because ASP.NET MVC will automatically detect anything ending with Controller via tthe routing configuration

Answer (score 0):

The **authentication** section in `Web.config` specify you have a login type:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Maybe your `Web.config` has a wrong configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm playing golf now but will test and accept answer later